# mybatis transaction rollback

Tags: java, spring, mybatis

**case 1：**

```
class TestService{
     @Autowired
     private SqlSessionTemplate sqlSession;

    public void insert(Map map1,Map map2,Map map3){
          sqlSession.insert("testMapper.insert",map1);
          sqlSession.insert("testMapper.insert",map2);
          sqlSession.insert("testMapper.insert",map3);
    }
}
```

**case 2：**

```
@Service
class ObjectService{
     @Autowired
     private SqlSessionTemplate sqlSession;

    public void insert(Map map){
          sqlSession.insert("testMapper.insert",map);
    }
}

class TestService{
     @Autowired
     private ObjectService objectService;

    public void insert(Map map1,Map map2,Map map3){
          objectService.insert(map1);
          objectService.insert(map2);
          objectService.insert(map3);
    }
}
```

I use mybatis and I have configured transactions using spring. I have a problem that the code described in the case #1 throws exception and the transaction is rolled back (so nothing is really inserted into database).

When I run case #2 the error is thrown again but data is still inserted into database and rollback does not happen.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Most probably you transaction configuration does not treat `TestService.insert` as a transactional method so it is not executed in transaction so each invocation of `objectService.insert` runs in its own transaction.

It means that for example the first invocation `objectService.insert(map1)` runs fine and the the problem happens during the second invocation. At that time the first transaction is already committed and even there is some problem with insertion of the second record the result of the first transaction is already persisted to database. And this looks like the absence of the rollback on the `TestService.insert`.